# Data scraping from NASDAQ-generated images

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to scrape the analyst recommendations from https://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/amzn/recommendations.

The problem is that the data is shown in the form of JPEG images, saved as:

```
https://www.nasdaq.com/charts/AMZN_cnb.jpeg
```

How are these images generated and is there a way to access the content in text-form?

Comment: You can buy these data from them legally.

Comment: can you explain what all data from the page you need?

Comment: I am looking to extract the numbers behind "Strong buy", "Buy", "Hold", "Sell", "Strong sell", i.e., 25, 2, 1, 0, 0.

Answer (score 0):

Using [**`BeautifulSoup`**](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) Library you can get desired data from the website.

Install [**`Requests`**](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) and `BeautifulSoup` by `pip`

- `pip install bs4`
- `pip install requests`

I hope this solves your query as i'm scraping Heading, Netchange, Percentage, and Recommendations from the website.

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = "https://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/amzn/recommendations"
raw = get(url)
soup = bs(raw.content, 'html5lib')
heading = soup.find('div', {"id":"qwidget_pageheader"}).text
dollar = soup.find('div', {"class": "qwidget-dollar"}).text
netchange = soup.find('div', {"id":"qwidget_netchange"}).text
percentage = soup.find('div', {"id":"qwidget_percent"}).text
recommendations = soup.find('ul', {"class":"floatL fontS14px"}).text
print(heading, dollar, netchange, percentage, recommendations)
```

---

Scrape the image and then you can use **`Pytessaract`** to extract text from image.

- `pip install pytessaract`
- install tessaract on system e.g On mac you use Brew so `brew install tessaract`

`Sample Code`

```
try:
    from PIL import Image
except ImportError:
    import Image
import pytesseract

def ocr_core(filename):
    """
    This function will handle the core OCR processing of images.
    """
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(filename))  # We'll use Pillow's Image class to open the image and pytesseract to detect the string in the image
    return text

print(ocr_core('images/ocr_example_1.png'))
```

Comment: Thanks! This works for the data that is available in text form, but not the data in the images:
https://www.nasdaq.com/charts/AMZN_cnb.jpeg